# How to connect a .NET application with WinDbg using API or Extension or IPC?

Tags: .net, windbg

Hi Guys,

I need to create a .NET application that can interact with WinDbg and extract data from it. People say to use DbgEng API. But what I need is an application that meets the following conditions:

I use WinDbg to debug an application say A

The second application I'm going to create in .NET say application B has to connect to WinDbg and provide the Code Flow of application A along with the register values, Call stacks, etc.. one by one as debugging goes on

If I need to read a memory I need to give command from B such that it goes into WinDbg and returns the memory dump of any given memory address and returns back to B

How can i do this? Is there a way like:

Build an extension for WinDbg such that connecting my .NET app B to it can provide interactivity or is there an API available for WinDbg or use IPC to connect WinDbg and my application B?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with a quick and dirty solution, you might be interested in using `.logopen` which will write the WinDbg output into a file and can probably be read from there. And have a look at `.ocommand` which can instruct WinDbg to take its command from another application sending commands via `OutputDebugString(...);`

Other than that, the question is very generic and would require a very long answer. This could be one reason why you were downvoted by a reviewer. First you might try to write just a small tutorial WinDbg extension so that you're familiar with writing WinDbg extensions in general. If that works, there will always be a way to interconnect with other programs through named pipes, HTTP or similar.

One question which comes up is: why would you like to do that? Your application B will probably never reach the functionality of WinDbg and just hinder doing actual debugging. Using DbgEng API is probably better than relying on the behavior of WinDbg, which is not a real API can can often have breaking changes.